# D3js Force Layout, dynamic links

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, visualization, force-layout

thanks for reading -- I am designing an interactive foreign language teaching tool using the D3js force bubble layout. In essence, users can select a language textbook chapter, part of speech, or specific word and the interface will display the word(s) in a series of bubbles each clustered together by their part of speech (adjective, noun, verb, etc.). These bubbles are free floating, no links between them.

When you click a word I have it open up more bubbles with information about that specific word (lexeme, meaning in english, frequency, etc.), but I want those bubbles to be attached to the original bubble with links. I'm having a lot of trouble conceptualizing how to do this dynamically (source -> target), even though it should be pretty straightforward.

First I draw the bubbles based on user input, some of which I've left out so the code doesn't get too long:

```
var nodes = d3.range(n).map(function(j) { return createNode(colorList, j); });
function createNode(info, j){
    var keys = objectKeys;
    var cluster, r;
    if (info[j].Lexeme.length < 3) {
        var radius = info[j].Lexeme.length * 15;
    }
    else {
        var radius = info[j].Lexeme.length * 5;
    }
    $.each(keys, function(x, y){
        if (info[j].POS == x){
            cluster = y;
        }
    });
    d = {cluster: cluster, radius: radius, info: info[j]};
    if (!clusters[cluster] || (r > clusters[cluster].radius)) clusters[cluster] = d;
    return d;
}

d3.layout.pack()
    .sort(null)
    .size([width, height])
    .children(function(d) { return d.values;})
    .value(function(d) { return d.radius * d.radius; })
    .nodes({values: d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.cluster; })
      .entries(nodes)});

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .size([width, height])
    .gravity(.00001)
    .charge(0)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();           

var svg = d3.select("#canvas").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var node = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", function (d, i) { return "node_n" + i; })
    .style("fill", function(d) {return d.info.fillColor;})
    .on("click", nodeSelect)
    .on("dblclick", infoNode)
    .call(force.drag);
    //Add the SVG Text Element to the svgContainer
    var text = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("text");

    //Add SVG Text Element Attributes
    text
     .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
     .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
     .text( function (d) { return d.info.Lexeme; })
     .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
     .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
     .attr("font-size", "13px")
     .attr("fill", "#000000");

node.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 5; })
    .attrTween("r", function(d) {
        var i = d3.interpolate(0, d.radius);
        return function(t) { return d.radius = i(t); };
    });

function tick(e) {

    node
      .each(cluster(5 * e.alpha * e.alpha))
      .each(collide(.3))
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

    text
       .attr("transform", transform);
}


function transform(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}

function nodeSelect(d) {
    if (d3.select(this).style("opacity") == 1 && nodeSelected == 0) {
        nodeSelected = 1;
        d3.select(this).style("opacity", ".3");
    }
    else if (d3.select(this).style("opacity") == .3 && nodeSelected == 1){
        nodeSelected = 0;
        d3.select(this).style("opacity", "1");
    }
}

// Move d to be adjacent to the cluster node.
function cluster(alpha) {
  return function(d) {
    var cluster = clusters[d.cluster];
    if (cluster === d) return;
    var x = d.x - cluster.x,
        y = d.y - cluster.y,
        l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
        r = d.radius + cluster.radius;
    if (l != r) {
      l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
      d.x -= x *= l;
      d.y -= y *= l;
      cluster.x += x;
      cluster.y += y;
    }
  };
}   

// Resolves collisions between d and all other circles.
function collide(alpha) {
  var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);
  return function(d) {
    var r = d.radius + maxRadius + Math.max(padding, clusterPadding),
        nx1 = d.x - r,
        nx2 = d.x + r,
        ny1 = d.y - r,
        ny2 = d.y + r;
    quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
        var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
            y = d.y - quad.point.y,
            l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
            r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + (d.cluster === quad.point.cluster ? padding : clusterPadding);
        if (l < r) {
          l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
          d.x -= x *= l;
          d.y -= y *= l;
          quad.point.x += x;
          quad.point.y += y;
        }
      }
      return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
    });
  };
}
function infoNodes(d){
    $.each(d.info, function(i, val){
        if (val != "" && val !="NA" && i != "fillColor"){
            var b = d.cluster;
            var r = 50;
            var q = {cluster: b, radius: r, info: val, fillColor: d.info.fillColor};
            if (!clusters[cluster] || (r > clusters[cluster].radius)) clusters[cluster] = q;
            nodes.push(q);
        }

    });
    update(d);

}


function update(j) {

    node = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes)
        .call(force.drag);

    node.enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", function (d, i) { return "info_" + d;})
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("r", function (d) { if (d.info.length < 5 || d.info.length == null) { return 30; } else { return d.info.length * 3.3; } })
        .style("fill", function(d) {return d.fillColor;})
        .call(force.drag);

    text = svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(nodes)
        .call(force.drag);

    text.enter().append("text")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .text( function (d) { return d.info; })
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-size", "13px")
        .attr("fill", "#000000")
        .call(force.drag);

    force.start();

}
```

The function can draw info nodes and update, but I can't figure out how to draw info nodes attached to the node you click with lines that connect them.

Let me know if more explanation is needed.

Comment: [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347) may help.

Comment: thanks for this! indeed it may!